# Why is, i.e.: 10^((77-109)/32), not working in Silverlight C#?

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to do the following:

```
10^((77-109)/32) = 0,1
```

In C#:

```
MessageBox.Show((Math.Pow((((77-109)/ 32)), 10)).ToString());
```

Output:

```
1
```

What is going on? How can I get the right answer?

Comment: The code you've given will print 0, not 1...

Comment: Your question is inconsistent; are you trying to do 77-109, or 88-109?

Comment: I corrected your question. Don't post fake code. Post real code. Use the clipboard. You want us to care about your problem. Show us that you also care by getting the question right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using all integers operands which leads C# to use integer arithmetics;

(88-109)/32 = (rounded down to) 0, and 0^10 = 0 (which is what your code line will display, not 1)

The correct line to get the result you want at the top of your question is;

```
MessageBox.Show((Math.Pow(10.0, (77.0 - 109.0) / 32.0)).ToString());
```

Which, correctly, will show 0.1. Note the change to decimal numbers instead of integers, and the swap of the (erroneous) `x^10` to `10^x`.

Comment: Pedantic I know. But it's more the use of integer arithmetic than the use of integer operands. Obviously all integer operands leads to ineger division.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, clarified that.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the inconvenience, my clipboard messed up.

Thanks for the code, that worked. I'm trying to Math.Pow multiple doubles, so when I tried 88 it was wrong again. Changing it to 88.0 worked :).

Answer (score 2):

You've swapped the parameters in `Math.pow`; your code is raising `(88-109)/32` to the power of 10, and as a result, you are getting unexpected results.  Swapping the parameters (and correcting 88 to 77) will give you the expected result of `0.1`, as it then will evaluate `10^-1`.

```
MessageBox.Show((Math.Pow(10, (77 - 109) / 32)).ToString());
```